# About resolving Resource Leaks

Tags: java, spring

I'm a newbee to spring framework and I encounted some errors when I was compiling the "HelloSpring" code on tutorialscom. Throughout the code there is only one warning in the main class:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        HelloWorld  HW = (HelloWorld)context.getBean("Hello Spring");
        HW.getMsg();
    }
}
```

Eclipse warns me "Resource Leak: 'context' is never close", but for ApplicationContext class I dont know how to close it. Can anyone help me with it?

The errors are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

BTW my java version is the latest 1.80, idk if this matters.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you're starting off, find something better than tutorialspoint. There are many tutorials written by Spring guys, and here's their [getting started](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview-getting-started-with-spring.html)
2. No one uses XML config anymore, unless you're 97 years old and against annotations. Use annotations.
3. You don't need a `try-finally` to close the `ApplicationContext`. [Try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) was introduced in Java 7 in 2011, about the same time people stopped using XML for Spring config.

I was gonna suggest you use Spring Boot and make life easier for yourself, but Boot does many things under the hood that you perhaps would like to learn the hard way.

Comment: Alright thank you! I will look into the link you send me

Answer (score 2):

Add commons-logging.jar to the project classpath. This will fix the error.

Regarding the warning by eclipse, you can place the code within try block and close the connection in finally block,it will fix the warning

```
ApplicationContext context = null;
try{
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
      }
finally{
  ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();

       }
```

Comment: Thank you! adding the .jar allows the program to run, but the 'context' in finally block has the error "context can not resolve to a variable". Do I need to add some other libraries?

Answer (score 1):

To fix your error : Add commons-logging.jar file to your project classpath. that will fix the issue.

To fix the resource leak : You have to register the shutdown hook. You can find more details here.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! It is really helpful!

Comment: He didn't ask for Spring Boot. He's just starting with Spring, which is why I didn't recommend using Boot in my answer.

Comment: No arguments here :) Just providing more information that might be helpful in the future.